# ¿Porqué no me permite publicar un @types npm?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

Estoy tratando de crear un @types para otro npm que me gusta mucho [fmt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fmt)

[image: imagen]

```
{
  "name": "@types/fmt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
  "deprecated": false,
  "scripts": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/PadRocha/-types-fmt.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/PadRocha/-types-fmt/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/PadRocha/-types-fmt#readme"
}
```

Este es el package.json

ingresé a mi usuario de npm correctamente

El error que regresa es el siguiente

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2ffmt - Forbidden
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\proch\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-21T23_02_32_967Z-debug.log
```

Cuando intento guardar un npm sin @types me lo permite pero con el mismo siempre me provoca el mismo error :(

Pensé que ya lo habrían creado pero cuando lo buscan [@types/fmt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/fmt) te muestra como que no existe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser que estás un poco confundido sobre como las declaraciones de tipos son publicadas. Dentro de la [documentación de TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html) encontrarás información sobre cómo es posible obtener dichas declaraciones, en concreto nos interesa el apartado que habla sobre **DefinitelyTyped/@types**:

> Definitions on DefinitelyTyped are also automatically published to npm under the @types scope.

DefinitelyTyped es un repositorio centralizado en el que se publican las declaraciones para miles de librerías que no cuentan con las mismas -declaraciones- por defecto (sucede mucho con paquetes que han sido escritos en JavaScript y no en TypeScript). La cita dice básicamente que toda aquella definición publicada dentro de ese repositorio estará disponible en el scope `@types`. Por lo que si quieres que las definiciones esten bajo ese scope, deberías leer [cómo contribuir](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-can-i-contribute) a ese repositorio para añadir nuevas definiciones.

Es por eso que al querer publicar en NPM obtienes un [error 403](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

> [...] una petición que resulta en un error 403 debería no ser repetida, y utilizar otra autorización no ayudará a que la petición se vuelva válida.

por lo que aunque brindes tus credenciales de accesso, el scope `@types` está "protegido" y solo es accesible con un PR satisfactorio a DefinitelyTyped.